# How to refactor nested each methods in ruby

Tags: ruby, refactoring, each

I have a large database of ingredients. I use custom classes to create the ingredients and their naming variations. OilSeed is one such class.

There are 64 naming variations for the following oil seed:

```
@oil_seed = OilSeed.new(
  common_name: "canola",
  genus: "brassica",
  species: ["capestris", "napus", "rapa", "rapa oleifera", "napus oleifera", "capestris oleifera"],
  oil_types: ["oil"],
  oil_derivatives: ["seed"],
  other_names: ["rapeseed", "polish canola", "rape"],
)
```

The class contains different methods used create the naming variations. Almost all the methods have a few levels of nested `.each` calls. The following one is the most complex. (Note that `create_name` is just a method call to something that actually creates the ingredient in the database).

```
def full_names(alt_names)
  alt_names.each do |alt_name|
    @oil_types.each do |oil_type|
      create_name("#{oil_type} of #{alt_name}")
      create_name("#{alt_name} #{oil_type}")

      @oil_derivatives.each do |oil_derivative|
        create_name("#{alt_name} #{oil_derivative} #{oil_type}")
      end
    end

    @scientific_names.each do |sn|
      @oil_types.each do |oil_type|
        create_name("#{scientific_names} (#{alt_name}) #{oil_type}")

        @oil_derivatives.each do |oil_derivative|
          create_name("#{scientific_names} (#{alt_name}) #{oil_derivative} #{oil_type}")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This method generates the following name variations for the seeds `common_name` and each of the `other_names` attrs.

- oil of canola
- canola oil
- canola seed oil
- brassica capestris (canola) oil
- brassica capestris (canola) seed oil

My code is working fine but I wanted advice on whether I should (or if I can) refactor the complex naming method. Firstly, because it's hard to tell what exactly is going on. And second, its a hassle to add new attributes to the  `OilSeed` class. Each time I need to add one it creates a mass of new `each` calls which is hard to maintain.

EDIT: Refactoring

```
def full_names(alt_names)
  combinations = generate_combinations(alt_names, @oil_types, @oil_derivatives)
  names = []

  combinations.each do |sn, ot, od|
    names << "#{sn} #{ot}"
    names << "#{sn} #{od} #{ot}"
  end

  create_names(names)
end

def generate_combinations(bases, *components)
  bases.flatten.product(*components)
end

def create_names(names)
  names.uniq.each { |x| create_name(x) }
end
```

Comment: Being that there is no pattern to the order of the variables within each inner loop, this makes refactoring here likely not possible/improvable. Even if so, it indicates you need some refactoring/restructuring to the design a layer above this, which isn't obvious with your current code sample. Could you perhaps include or explain the `build` method, or explain what exactly what end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: `build` is a method that's inputing the string into something else. I thought it would be clearer with a's and b's, but I'll edit the question to try and provide more information and a proper code sample.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 Please take a look and let me know what you think. I'd appreciate any advice you can give!

Comment: Perhaps some sub-classing would help make things a bit more manageable, splitting some things into separate methods, such as `scientific_names` and `oil_types` loops, but really the most helpful thing would be to plan out your design hierarchy first and then implement, instead of implementing, then trying to add to it. Using properly planned hierarchy, you can start with the most basic, then subclass and add functionality for more specific functionality. Also, does this need to be a hash, or could you convert it to a class?

Comment: Does what need to be a hash? The code could have definitely been planned out better. It started as a small attempt to simplify an unmanageable amount of seeds. It could probably use proper planning before it gets unwieldy while implementing the other seed classes. What do you think of my updated solution?

Comment: Disregard my hash comment, I misread a part of it :P Seems to be an improvement. I might even separate the method, one to build the `combinations`, another the `full_names`. This way if you need to change any functionality for a specific situation, it becomes much easier, and makes the code more flexible and maintainable.

Comment: No worries. It looks loads better now! This was exactly the kind of adjustment I was looking for. I'll try applying the same logic to the rest of the code.  Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: As an aside `collect` will create an `Array` that you are not using at all. Either change this to `each` or use something like `flat_map` e.g. `generate_combinations(components).flat_map {|on, sn, ot, od| #[your combinations go here]}.uniq.each(&method(:create_name))`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for that! I updated the current state of the methods to include .each and a new method to create names. Is there any reason why flat.map would be preferable here? They both seem to be doing the same thing from what I can see.

Comment: @rosalynn `flat_map` was just a suggestion to allow for chaining as `each` would not allow such a thing and `map` (`collect`) would have created an `Array` of `Array`s

Comment: Ah okay. While no longer necessary here, thats really good to know for the future. Thanks again

Comment: @engineersmnky but great suggestion for `(&method(:create_name))`, I didn't know that syntax could take an argument.